# Dynamically add simple products to bundle

Tags: quote, bundled-product

We have 1000 simple products that we want to be a part of a bundle. We are not sure if the Admin interface for bundle products can handle 1000 simple products.

So we want to load specific simple products that we show to the user as a choice and add the simple product they choose to the bundle that goes into the cart quote.

Example:

1. User goes to product page for the bundled product.
2. We load a collection of 20 simple products of the 1000 simple
   products and the user chooses one of those products.
3. We add the simple product to the bundle and add it to the cart
   quote.

Need to know how I would do this and if it is possible.

Comment: 1000 products are no problem, but be careful with php.inis `max_input_vars`

Comment: I switched to using a simple product and custom options with the Advanced Custom Options module by MageWorx. Then I can import the product data when I need to update the assigned products. Plus ACO can sync my product prices.